# How do attack rolls work?

Tags: attack, shadowrun-sr5

Where is the page in the 5e core rulebook that states how attack rolls function, specifically in meatspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pages 44-47 discuss how the mechanics of die rolls work to succeed. Pay particular attention to Hits and Thresholds and opposed tests, which is what combat usually consists of in meat space.

Page 174 gives examples of using those rules for melee and ranged attacks. Pages 158-198 cover the many, many different types of actions and modifiers to things like melee and ranged weapons, full auto, multiple attacks, called shots, dodge, parry, etc.

There's a sequence on page 173 that may also help understand the basic flow.

Answer (score 2):

The editing of the english version of the core rulebook is lacking. Information that belongs together is often spread out, not just in the same chapter, but also all over the book.

The short answer: page 173

My prefered way of dealing with it: Cheat sheets. Players have written up some nice documents helping new players get into the game. See this as an example: http://www.extell.us/sr/Shadowrun_5th_Edition_Cheat_Sheet.pdf